# php abstract class extending method parameter type or type hint type

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

Consider this case, I have an abstract class, which children take a blueprint and do different actions with it. Now I have multiple classes which extend this and perform slightly different actions with the blueprint, thus I have extended versions of said blueprint, which I need each of the child classes to get.

As such I want to define / type hint the property or respective function input property in the abstract class as any and then specify the property type in each of the child classes.

But I cannot do this, because PHP 7 gives me an error

```
Declaration B::setBlueprint() must be compatible with A::setBlueprint()
```

The blueprint classes

```
class Blueprint {
    public $id;
}

class ChildBlueprint extends ParentBlueprint {
    public $someOtherPropINeedOnlyInThisClass;
}
```

and the abstract classes that consume those blueprints

```
abstract class A {
    abstract public function setBlueprint( ParentBlueprint $_ );
}

class B extends A {
    public function setBlueprint( ChildBlueprint $_ ) {}
}
```

I mean I need a blueprint that is derived from the  in all of the A, B, C, ..., X, Y classes and as such it makes no sense to leave it out of the abstract class.

What are good OOP solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could overcome this with implementing dependency inversion:

```
interface Blueprint {
}

class ParentBluePrint implements Blueprint
{
    public $id;
}

class ChildBluePrint extends ParentBlueprint
{
    public $id;
}

abstract class A
{
    abstract public function setBlueprint( Blueprint $_ );
}

class B extends A
{
    public function setBlueprint( Blueprint $_ ) {}
}
```

See more about relevant SOLID Principle [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-4-the-dependency-inversion-principle--net-36872).

Comment: The issue is that B should not accept Blueprint, because it needs ChildBluePrint, because of some of it's unique properties. So accepting blueprint is misleading, when it actually needs a child blueprint. And both A and B have a blueprint, which is the basis of their functionality, so it makes no sense to name the blueprint differently in B, so I can set a different parameter type to it's setter function. Yet all the blueprints still share 90% of the same properties, so on an abstract level, they are definately derivateive of each other.